# Visual Studio - How to debug XSLT passing parameters?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xslt

In the `Transform` method of the `System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform` class has an override to accept argument list (`System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList`). This can be used for passing extra parameters to the XSLT. Visual studio has a nice debugging feature that enables you to debug XSLT. It, however, accepts an input and output the result to the specified file. Is there a way I can pass additional arguments to the debugger?

Comment: Looks no one is interested!

Comment: I'm interested.  Good question.  Too bad nobody answered as I have the same question.

Comment: I'm guessing Microsoft doesn't support it.    If you found an alternative let us know.  VS code seems to have XSLT debug support so maybe it is better.  Let us know by answering your own question if you found a way to do it even if it was with another tool or via an extension to visual studio.